# Can I check if no arguments are given without comparing default values?

Tags: python, arguments, default, args

```
class Test:
    def test_fun(self, a=0, b=0):
        # code
```

Is there a way to check if `test_fun` has no arguments given, `test_fun()`, without comparing `if a==0` and `if b==0`?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Doesn't that defeat the purpose of having default values?

Comment: You could maybe use `kwargs` and check the length of `kwargs`. @rdas there are some built-in functions (e.g. `range()`) that behave differently depending on whether one argument is given or whether two or more are. Maybe look at the internals and see how `range()` implements it and copy that design pattern?